# Visual Basic. i have problem of Mysql connection with visual basic code

Tags: vb.net

i have been dealing with this issues for the last days and unfortunately i couldn't fix until now. anytime i run the  code i got this error message:

> <<MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'new_time_and_attendance''>>

the entire code is below:

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class main_form
    Dim mysqlconn As MySqlConnection
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.Close()
        Form1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        verificationform.Close()
        verificationform.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Sub loadenrolleddata()
        Dim drt As MySqlDataReader
        Dim nm As String
        fptemplist.Clear()
        listofnames.Clear()
        Dim mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString = Form1.connection

        If mysqlconn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            mysqlconn.Open()
        End If

        nm = "select personnelid,fingerdata1,fingerdata2,fingerdata3,fingerdata4,fingerdata5,fingerdata6,fingerdata7,fingerdata8," _
            & "fingerdata9,fingerdata10 from new_enrollment"

        'nm = "select personnelid,fingerdata7" _
        '   & "from new_enrollment where length(fingerdata7) > 0 "

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
        cmd.CommandText = nm
        cmd.Connection = mysqlconn
        drt = cmd.ExecuteReader
        'MetroProgressBar1.Maximum = drt.FieldCount
        While drt.Read()
            Dim mstram As IO.MemoryStream

            For i = 1 To 10
                Dim fpbytes As Byte()
                fpbytes = drt("fingerdata" & i)
                mstram = New IO.MemoryStream(fpbytes)
                If fpbytes.Length > 0 Then
                    Dim temp8 As DPFP.Template = New DPFP.Template
                    temp8.DeSerialize(mstram)
                    fptemplist.Add(temp8)
                    listofnames.Add(drt("personnelid"))
                End If
            Next
        End While
        drt.Close()
        mysqlconn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub main_form_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        loadenrolleddata()
    End Sub

    Private Sub main_form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseEnter
        Button1.Image = My.Resources.security_bnr_fp
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.MouseLeave
        Button1.Image = My.Resources._21b6e9221d1b4cb5c62caa1a9b111c84_13
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseEnter
        Button2.Image = My.Resources.ICN_precise_recog
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseLeave
        Button2.Image = My.Resources.dda52d7a57a74a94e182f4cf8898d2bf_0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.MouseEnter
        Button5.Image = My.Resources.fingerprint
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.MouseLeave
        Button5.Image = My.Resources._1cf6b14d2eea4c37dba8bc0ac12235a3_0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        clockinout.Close()
        clockinout.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        reports.Close()
        reports.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StatusStrip1_ItemClicked(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles StatusStrip1.ItemClicked

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The problem is probably with the [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/), not with the VB code.

Comment: The error message literally tells you what the problem is.

Comment: (You should be calling `mysqlconn.Dispose()` after the line `mysqlconn.Close()`. Or better, use the Using statement to make sure that connection is automatically disposed of, the same way as for an [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection).)

Answer (score 0):

That error is not related to the code. It's telling you that the MySQL client can't connect to the database you've asked it to.

This is almost certainly down to incorrect information in the connection string you are using so double-check that first.